# SmtpClient is not working with values given in constructor

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I found this weird problem with SmtpClient class. I am not sure is this the correct behavior  or not. So the problem is when I give my host name and port into constructor of "SmtpClient" class. it does not work. it gives me this error.
"The server committed a protocol violation. The server response was: UGFzc3dvcmQ6".

I tried to find this error on google as well, but nothing worked for me.
code for this is below:

> 

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("<Host name>","port number");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<User name>", "password");
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("<From Email>");
mailMessage.To.Add("<To Email");
mailMessage.Body = "test";
mailMessage.Subject = "test";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

But If I give "host" and "port" in property then it works fine. code for this is here

>

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();//_settings.EmailSetting.Host);
 client.Host = "<hostName>";
 client.Port=<Port Number>;
 client.EnableSsl = true;
 client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<User name>", "password");
 MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
 mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("<From Email>");
 mailMessage.To.Add("<To Email");
 mailMessage.Body = "test";
 mailMessage.Subject = "test";
 client.Send(mailMessage);
```

is there anybody else who faced the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turn logging on for `System.Net.Mail` and check what happened:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing#configure-network-tracing

Also `UGFzc3dvcmQ6` is Base64 encoded "Password:", meaning the server was asking for a password.

Comment: yes I found that "UGFzc3dvcmQ6" is encoded version of password. I tried to give password in base 64, but that did not work as well. Let me go through url which you have given. Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

In network credentials give only "username" without domain. for example: instead of "DOMAIN\username" give "username" only.